# Is there a way to multiply current?

Tags: transistors, current, amplifier, dc

I'm playing with a small 6V ceramic heater. However when I connect it to my 12V .8A DC source it pulls it to 0.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

But when I connect it to 4AA batteries it works just fine. I was thinking that the current is not enough from my ppeer source. Is there a CCT I could make to get this heater to work with my 12V,.8A?

Comment: What is the actual current draw?

Comment: A DC-DC converter could supply up to about 1.5 amps at 6 volts from your 12 volt 0.8 amp supply.  What current does your heater require?  Or what is its power rating?

Comment: Your supply can only provide 9.6 watts of power, (12 x 0.8).  So even with a DC-DC converter if your ceramic heater is rated > 9.6 watts you're going to overload the supply.

Comment: If this heater works with 4 AA batteries, then it can't be rated for more than a couple of watts which doesn't seem very useful. Can you measure how much current these batteries are supplying? How long does it work with the 4 AA batteries? Something doesn't make sense.

Comment: i am not sure of the actual draw. but it did work for about 5 mins of testing before i disconnected it . the heater specs . 6v . 6 ohm .

Comment: ok its waay of based on the calculations it rated at 60 watts .

Answer (score 3):

Let me get this straight.  You connected something rated for **6 V** to something that produces **12 V**, and you're actually surprised something went wrong!!?  You are trying to cram 20 pounds of stuff into a 10 pound bag.  It doesn't take a degree in engineering or much sense at all to expect this not to work out.

The 12 V supply can put out up to 800 mA.  Apparently your heater draws more than that when connected to 12 V.  This type of heater is basically just a resistor.  For it to only draw 800 mA at 12 V, it would need to draw only 400 mA at 6 V.  That means it would be rated as (6 V)(400 mA)= 2.4 W or less at 6 V.  If it is rated at higher power than that, then it will draw more current than 400 mA at 6 V or 800 mA at 12 V and your 12 V supply can't handle it.

Apparently your 12 V supply has a shutdown feature so that it goes to 0 V when you try to abuse it, as you did.  It may periodically try to raise the voltage for a short time, discover the current is still too high, and go back into shutdown.  These attempts to recover would be short blips maybe every second or two, so you'd still see 0 V on a meter measuring the output.

Fortunately for you, all that happened was that the supply shut down.  If you had connected the heater to a 12 V source with more current capability, like a car battery for example, the heater would have to give instead of the supply.  Again, ceramic heaters are basically just resistors with fancy marketing, and generally don't come with any protection circuitry.  The 2x voltage would cause 4x the power dissipation, which would very likely be destructive to the heater within a few seconds.

The 4 AA batteries work with the heater because they are running it within spec.  At roughly 1.5 V per cell, they make 6 V, which is what the heater is designed to operate at.  This again should be no surprise.

There are ways to take 12 VDC at some current and make 6 VDC at not quite twice the current.  A circuit for this is called a *buck converter*, but that is above your level of electronics at this point.  Nothing called a "transformer" will work since those inherently run on AC, not DC.

Comment: Even thought my source is rated 12v . It's variable source . So no I didn't connect it to the full 12 v.

Answer (score 1):

Current can be multiplied but power cannot.  your 12V supply is only capable of about 10W it's never going to power a 60W appliance.

That 60W heater is going to need a 6V supply capable of prducing 10A of current to operate at full power. On a 5V supply capable of 9A you'll 
get about 42W out. If those AA bater ies are nickel based rechargables they're probably running it at about 35-40W somewhere due to their voltage being about 1.2V per cell.

if that resistande is actually six ohms divide all the power and amps numbers above by 10, and you can use a buck converter to reduce the 12V supply down to 6V at about 1.4A capacity, which would be enough.